# Can we simulate compressible flows by simple direct explicit calculation, without solving systems of linear equations (such as Poisson eq)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes, vorticity

Is this is plausible at all? It seems the most obvious/naive approach, so there's probably good reasons why it's not used - what are they?

Viscosity is not important.

Starting with inviscid Navier Stokes:

$$
  \frac{\partial \mathbf u}{\partial t} +
    \mathbf u \cdot \nabla \mathbf u +
    \frac{1}{\rho} \nabla p = \mathbf f
$$

Conserve mass by tracking density as a state variable. We advect it and update it with the divergence of the velocity:

$$
  \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} =
    - \mathbf u \cdot \nabla \rho
    - \rho ( \nabla \cdot \mathbf u )
$$

Next, calculate pressure from density:

$$
    p = \frac{1}{\alpha} ( \frac{\rho}{\rho_0} - 1 )
$$

Now, we have pressure $p$ and we can use its gradient to calculate the change in $\mathbf u$ from the first Navier Stokes equation (rearranged from above)
$$
  \frac{\partial \mathbf u}{\partial t} =
    - \mathbf u \cdot \nabla \mathbf u
    - \frac{1}{\rho} \nabla p
   + \mathbf f
$$

This idea is similar to simulating the Shallow Water equations, where the velocity divergence is used to update the height of the water. The height is like a 2d density (mass per area). The weight of the fluid causes pressure. Differences in pressure (gradient) cause accelerations in the velocity field.

However, I don't seem to get any eddies/vorticity from simulating the Shallow Water equations, so I wonder if there's some fundamental problem with this idea...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Physically, vorticity can only be created (as opposed to transported, stretched or intensified **after** being created) either by the appearance of a boundary layer on a solid surface, or through the pressure gradient not being parallel to the density gradient. For the shallow water equation without viscosity neither mechanism is available, so congratulations, your code is making a correct prediction. Quite often though vorticity does appear on account of numerical viscosity. It appears in more or less the same place that vorticity would appear with real viscosity. It might or might not be relevant to the true situation

EDIT The non creation of vorticity is revealed by the evolution equation of vorticity for an inviscid compressible gas in two dimensions;
$$\partial_t\omega+\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\omega+\omega\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}+\frac{\nabla{p}\times\nabla{\rho}}{\rho^2}=0$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm vconcerned about this, because I discretized the above and it came out equivalent to the shallow water equations - I'd like effects llke swirling cigarette smoke. Could you elaborate on "**pressure gradient not being parallel to the density gradient**" please? How does that cause vorticity? How does it arise in nature? What is missing from my equations? (I see they are parallel in my scheme and in the shallow water equations). Sorry, all these questions are probably too much to ask, but this sounds like the key! *PS* I'm using semi-lagrangian advection, which dissipates greatly.

Comment: Right, shallow water is just isentropic gas dynamics with $\gamma=2$. Flows in which the pressure is a function only of the density (in SW pressure is proportional to the square of the height and density is proportional to the height) are called barotropic. Now consider a flow for which this is not true and a small spherical element. Because the pressure force on any part of the surface passes through the center of the sphere, so does the total pressure force, which is in the direction of the pressure gradient.The pressure force acts along a line parallel to the gradient and through the c.g.

Comment: If the spheres c.g. does not also lie on this line, then the sphere will rotate.
Surprisingly even tangential forces do not create vorticity, as can be seen by taking the curl of velocity equations. Vorticity is created only (except as above) at solid surfaces, and then diffuses into the general flow, or is carried there by a separating boundary layer. You seem interested in some kind of simulation for the movies or for video games. I am told that the greatest factor ibn the credibility of such a simulation is the behavior of vorticity,

Comment: Oops, in my first comment replace c.g. by geometric center

Comment: Thanks! I've studied your comments. I assume c.g. in the second is center of gravity? (makes sense). If "small spherical element" has same pressure throughout, then I see that external pressures act through its geometric center (I guess that's the definition of "element"). I see that if the center of gravity of that element is not at its geometric center, then a force through its center will produce torque and rotational acceleration.

Comment: How to modify my equations to allow vorticity? (through offset density, not the boundary layers due to viscosity) First, track density and pressure as separate state variables. I've been using a MAC grid, which tracks each velocity component between the pressures that accelerate it (i.e. vertical velocity component has a pressure above and below; horizontal velocity component has pressures left and right) If density was tracked at the same points as pressure, there couldn't be an offset, and no rotation? Could calculate density as above, but how to calculate pressure, if not via density?

Comment: Calculating the curl of the velocity seems the right way to prove vorticity doesn't arise! I tired this with the shallow water equations, but didn't get that result. How should I approach this?

Comment: I looked up "isentropic", which is "reversible adiabatic", which means temperature may change instead of being lost to/gained from the surroundings. Retaining the same energy allows it to be reversible. γ is (specific heat at constant pressure) over (specific heat at constant volume). The shallow water equations are 2d, and so have 2 degrees of freedom f=2 and γ=(f+2)/f=2. This seems surprising, but it makes sense that degrees of freedom have something to do with disorderedness (entropy). I don't really understand any of this. But I'm imterested: how does it  relate to vorticity?

Comment: Finally: yes, I'm interested in a video game simulation. The fluid game/movie literature uses incompressible flows and does emphasise vorticity, e.g. using Helmholtz decomposition to project the non-divergent velocity component (as opposed to the irrotational component). There's even an approach that tracks vorticity itself as a state variable. All this comes from cfd though. I want to try an explicit compressible scheme, because (I think) it's simpler to grasp, code and debug; a small timestep is fine for what I want to do (weather system); and you'd get sound (pressure waves) for free!

Comment: PS I really am asking way too much here! Just getting the gist of your answer is enough - thanks very much for that! (Saving my further questions here is a helpful record of them for me in the future.)

Comment: Oh... the gradient of a scalar field, like pressure, is necessaeily irrotational, because otherwise a circuit could infinitely ascend or descend.

Comment: Small spherical element does not need to have constant pressure. We are only interested in the case of a pressure gradient, but the pressure on ANY part of the sphere must give a force through the center. Degrees of freedom don't come into it. It is rather coincidental that the shallow water assumption $p\propto h^2$ gives the same governing equations as taking $\gamma=2$ in the isentropic equation of state for a gas $p=\rho^\gamma$. To discuss vorticity, in either case, write the time derivatives of velocity in non-conservative form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58521/discussion-between-philip-roe-and-hyperpallium).

Comment: Hi, I don't think scicomp gives notifications for talk, so you mightn't have seen my further questions in "chat" over the last few weeks. They are probably way too much to see all at once! I plan to try your symmetry-breaking boundary suggestion later night.

Comment: With faster velocity for the jet, I got twin vortices the head of the jet, as it moved across. There's a head of pressure, where the jet hits stationary water, and this seems to part the jet into the twin counter-rotating vortices, one on each side. I tried a box, adjacent to the jet, and this modified the vortices (reminds me of the vortex in a windtunnel "backstep" setup). I don't see viscosity playing a role in these specific cases... could you suggest a reference for how viscosity causes vorticity, please? (There's more detail on this issue in "chat", but it's not focussed)

Comment: Reviewing your answer, these 3 cases don't seem to be covered (maybe I misunderstand terminology, or they don't count as *vorticity* somehow): **1** water through a coiled garden hose; **2** filling a circular children's pool with a hose tangential to the wall causes a "whirlpool"; **3** a jet of water in stationary water forms a head of pressure, which acts in all directions, including laterally, thus beginning a circular motion. (My discretization grid has $p$ at cell centres, $u$ and $v$ at grid edges, so the lateral pressure is straightforwardly apparent, and vortices do form there).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation (*Understanding Aerodynamics*, Doug McLean), but I wonder if you could suggest an online resource for this "vorticity from viscosity"? Maybe a survey paper, or just a paper with a nice intro section? Unfortunately, McLean is $300 (in Australia), and not available in nearby university libraries. On google books, I read its *vorticity* section, but couldn't folllow it with the missing pages... I did find and watch McLean's 1 hour video lecture on the topic.

Comment: The libraries should have Viscous flow by Frank White. This is an excellent text.

Comment: Thanks, it's available! Did you see my other comment?

Comment: White discusses the problem of a deep container whose floor is impulsively started. There is an exact solution. Vorticity is confined to a boundary layer that grows like $t^{1/2}$. That is typically how vorticity is created.

Comment: Old puzzle, why can you easily blow a flame out but not suck it out? Try with candle and straw. A directed jet must have vorticity on its boundary. When you blow, there is preexisting vorticity created by boundary layers on your lungs/throat/mouth, which is in place to do this job. If you suck, this vorticity is not present. Instead of a fast jet, get a slow isotropic convergence.

Comment: Those are interesting cases, and I want to learn more about that kind of vorticity; but they don't address the 3 cases I raised, which don't involve a boundary layer (the comment I meant is the 6th above, and at this link: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/can-we-simulate-compressible-flows-by-simple-direct-explicit-calculation-withou#comment48936_26830)

Comment: EVERYTHING INVOLVES A BOUNDARY LAYER. You want to manipulate a fluid. You introduce a solid object or another fluid with a different velocity. Boundary layers in every case, inside the hose, on the wall of the pool, in the layer where the fluids meet.

Comment: Yes, there's a boundary layer, and vorticity due to that - but in the case of a coiled garden hose (say, coiled with a radius of 1 foot, as they commonly are), the circular motion of water as it travels around the large circle of the coil will be vorticity, in the sense that the $cirl$ of the velocity field at any infinitesimal point will be slightly non-zero due to the slight curve that forms the 1 foot radius circle (i.e. not the tiny vorticies within the hose, but the "vortex" with a radius of 1 foot). If frictionless hose walls, there would be no boundary layer, and so no other vorticity.

Comment: It is actually quite hard to tell when vorticity is present. The classical potential vortex has $u\propto\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, v\propto\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$.The curl of this is zero. It is an irrotational vortex. This flow is singular at the origin, and viscous forces are large there even if viscosity is small. A 'core' of rotating flow is formed and grows with time but very slowly.

In the coiled hose, water travels in a circle, but will not become rotational until the boundary layer has done its work. With a frictionless hose, there would be no vorticity. In 2d the solution would be as above.

Comment: I don't understand, but being assured there's *some* flaw in my reasoning is enough. I will wait to gain more background. I thought curl = vorticity. I would have thought there would be slightly greater pressure on the outer side of the hose, acting as a sort of "pressure wall" for the water a little further away from that wall - forming a pressure gradient. A bend in a stream is similar, with water heaping up on the outer bank. Maybe there's something funky with the outer water having to travel a little further (because longer radius), and might counter rotate. Thanks for your forebearance!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62132/discussion-between-philip-roe-and-hyperpallium).

Comment: Surely fluid moving in a circle has angular momentum? (more in chat)

Comment: I gave a clearer description of how I see the physics in chat. BTW. I think you can edit previous chat comments with up-arrow (but only for a very short time).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can apply some explicit scheme to discretize the equations. The explicit approach is just impractical for stiff problems due to stability constraints on the time step. See the [Explicit and implicit methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_and_implicit_methods) page on Wikipedia for more details.